# How to find solution of the integral equation?

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, periodic-functions

$$y(t) + t \int_0^t y(v)dv = 1 + \int_0^t vy(v)dv$$

I found the answer to be $y(t) = \cos{t}$. I have no idea how they go this answer. I would appreciate any suggestions how to solve this.

Comment: Please double check that I have interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: Are you given any more information about $y(v)?$ Like is it integrable or differentiable?

Comment: @abiessu yes, that's correct. @ graydad I was only given that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiate (left side) - (right side) twice and you'll get
$$ y'' + y = 0$$
so $y(t) = a \cos(t) + b \sin(t) $.
Plug that in to your integral equation and you'll find that you need $a=1$, $b=0$.